# rational power transcendental

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

A common example that rational power transcendental number is rational is $2^{\log_2 3}$.The irrationality of $2^{e}$ and $2^{\pi}$ is still unknown.  Gelfond-Schneider theorem gives the answers only for irrational power. Is there is any example, such that, rational number raised to transcendental number is transcendental or irrational.

Comment: @arturomagidin I could be mistaken, but I think he means a rational number to a transcendental power. It's a little unclear, tho...

Comment: @james.nixon: yes, it's not been clarified....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  I am asking about $\alpha^{\beta}$ is irrational or transcendental, where $\alpha$ is rational and $\beta$ is transcendental.

Comment: @user157835: you've clarified, thank you. That's why I deleted the comment.

Comment: Well, $2^{(\log_2 3)/2}=\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 6):

"Rational to transcendental power is irrational" is easy given the transcendence of numbers like $\log_2 3$, e.g.
$2^{\frac12 \log _{\,2}\! 3} = \sqrt 3$.  For a transcendental example, once numbers like $3^{\sqrt 2}$ are known to be transcendental you can use
$2^{\sqrt 2 \log_{\,2} \!3}$.

Comment: yup got it, thanks, Actually all such examples always contain $\log$ term in their power, so its property easily gives a result. but what about if power is not in terms of $\log$?

Comment: Well $a^x = b$ is equivalent to $x = \log_a b$, so if $a$ is rational then $x$ is naturally written as a log.